React native app shows blank screen due to misconfigured side drawer
i'm devloping a library app for learning react native, but i were not able to setup a side drawer.
when i configure my side drawer implementation (through root layout ) my react native app gives blank screen
if i revert back my root layout file to below code everything works fine, but no side drawer.
import { Stack } from "expo-router";
import React from "react";

export default function AuthRoutesLayout() {
  return <Stack />;
}

my problamatic root layout file is shared below
import "../global.css";
import { Drawer } from "expo-router/drawer";
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";

export default function Layout() {
  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Drawer screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="auth"
          options={{
            drawerLabel: "",
            drawerItemStyle: { height: 0 }
          }}
        />
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="auth/Login"
          options={{
            drawerLabel: "",
            drawerItemStyle: { height: 0 }
          }}
        />
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="Explore"
          options={{
            drawerLabel: "Explore",
          }}
        />
      </Drawer>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
}

i can confirm that the error is coming from root layout file only
can anyone help me on this?
my folder structure is as shown below
app 
  auth 
    index.tsx 
    login.tsx 
    signup.tsx 
  Explore.tsx
  index.tsx
  _layout.tsx

my other files are also shared below
my root index.tsx code

import { AuthProvider } from "@/contexts/auth.context";
import { Redirect } from "expo-router";

export default function Index() {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <Redirect href="/auth" />
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}


my auth/index.tsx file is
import { useAuthContext } from "@/contexts/auth.context";
import { Redirect,  } from "expo-router";
import {  Text, View } from "react-native";

export default function Auth() {
  const { loggedIn } = useAuthContext();
  if (loggedIn) {
    <Redirect href="/Explore" />
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Auth index</Text>
    </View>
  );
}


I were able to fix the issue by following the tutorial following pinned tutorial.
